# Javascript to add marker to images

Tags: javascript, image, onclick, marker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a marker to an image in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624202/add-a-marker-to-an-image-in-javascript)

Is there a Javascript solution that, when it loads, shows a set of markers? Ideally, these markers, when clicked or tapped on a touch device, open up a information window. This is basically what Google Maps does. However, I would like to do this for images and not on a map.

Here's an example I just draw.

[image: image and markers]

If I were to code this up, do you have any recommendations on other libraries to use, etc? I was thinking of making a jQuery plugin.

Credit for the image goes to [dancentury@flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/dancentury/160533445/sizes/o/in/photostream/).

Comment: Slightly different. I'm asking for already existing solutions. Also, that question is from 2009. There might be better ways to do it today.