# Javascript place marker on image onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this map that will place coordinates into inputfields when you click on the map. It would be great to have a marker to place on the map that will show where was clicked.

Only thing is that the examples I find will leave all of the points on the map when you re-click it, while I only need a marker on the last position clicked on the image.
Anyone that can help with this?
It is like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624202/add-a-marker-to-an-image-in-javascript) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26123410/placing-a-dot-on-an-image-onclick) example. The first one is good but will place marker image under the image itself, and the second one will leave all of the dots on the image.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: You get the logic. Now to remove any previous one, you could just set a class or id or whatever and remove any previous one, e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/95vczfve/37

Comment: Well that is exactly what I was looking for. Javascript is certainly not my area of expertise so it was best to ask. Thanks a lot! @A.Wolff

Comment: Hmm, this is adding a `div` to the body and then setting the dot in the div, however this will not work for an actual image? When I do it will put it behind the image i guess

Comment: Then this isn't what you are looking for. You should search for "edit image using canvas" but this is subject to same origin policy. See e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053687/how-to-load-image-on-canvas-and-put-markers-on-click  But again, you'd need to remove previoud marker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extending the accepted solution on [Add a marker to an image in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26123580/1369473)

I just added a unique class to the appending div and then removed all elements with that class on every click event.

**MODIFIED CODE:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(document).click(function (ev) {
        if($('div').length < 3) {
            $(".marker").remove();      // remove all existing markers
            $("body").append(            
                $('<div class="marker"></div>').css({       // include a class
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: ev.pageY + 'px',
                    left: ev.pageX + 'px',
                    width: '10px',
                    height: '10px',
                    background: '#000000'
                })              
            );
        }
    });

});
```

See the action: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rdpuxajo/)

Update as requested in comment: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rdpuxajo/2/)

Comment: Thanks, but like i commented on the other one, this will append the body and will not be possible for an actual `<img>`? Since it's adding a div to it. I'm not sure @Fr0zenFyr

Comment: @dnsko see the update. I just put the image tag inside `<body></body>` and used pretty much the same javascript.

Comment: the trick is to position the marker as `absolute` and the parent container as `relative` which is already there. If this is still not what you want, then I probably don't understand your requirement clearly.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I want, thing is that i just cannot get it to work for me. The page is full of forms, buttons and a map image. Wherever I click in the body it will display the square marker, except when I click on the image (seems like it places it behind the images, on the body itself). @Fr0zenFyr

Comment: I don't think so, can you post a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with your HTML markup and JS so that I can have a look?

Comment: I have created a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/s82n35hk/1/). It is a generic project, therefore the small html but it should give an idea of what the structure is for the image (i chose a random map for this). Hope this helps a bit @Fr0zenFyr

Comment: Can you check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdpuxajo/3/). I just used the relevant HTML from your fiddle to demonstrate it there. Also, instead of `onclick="point_it(event)"` in HTML, you can do that stuff in javascript like `$("#pointer_div").on('click', function(event) { ... })` .

Comment: That is exactly it! Thanks alot for the effort! @Fr0zenFyr

Comment: @dnsko Glad I could help. If you think the answer helped you, you can accept the solution by clicking on the check mark at left of my answer and probably upvote it too? :)

Answer (score 1):

Not the best method, but the simpliest I coult think about
Shortest code I could make to do it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Bla!
        </title>
        <style type='text/css'>
            div.divImgContainer { position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; bottom:10px; right:10px;  border: 1px solid black; }
            div#divMark { position:absolute; top:-100px;  left:-100px; background-color:red; width:3px; height:3px;}
        </style>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function ShowMarker(event) {
                //console.log (event);
                console.log (event);
                var mark = document.getElementById('divMark');
                mark.style.top =  (event.clientY)+'px';
                mark.style.left = (event.clientX) +'px';
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='divImgContainer' onclick='ShowMarker(event);'>
            <!-- set image as background to this div -->
        </div>
        <div id='divMark' ><!-- you can change the "x" to image of marker if needed --></div>
    </body>
</html>
```