# Add marker to image and make it responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093549/javascript-place-marker-on-image-onclick) guide to put out markers and it works well. However, I want to save those markers in a database and make it responsive.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use ajax to send positions to server

Comment: But the position will be relative to my screen, wont it? In that case, it will not look similar on the phone

Comment: Convert to percent then